# UIBezier Path moveToPoint method

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

Well I guess this applies to paths in general. Do I have to start a graphics context before I start to define or modify a UIBezierPath? I do not need to draw the path, just modifying the path in preparation of drawing in another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, UIBezierPath is not related to drawing. It just let you specify geometry of your path

Comment: The same is true when creating a CGPath